# Discord Bot Replit

Tags: discord.py, replit

I tried making a Discord Bot on Replit and everything seemed to work but now a day later it gives me a error i cant identify i think its smt about the Token. But Im not sure also I never did smt in Python. So this is my first Project based on a tutorial which i edited some parts of it.

**Script:**

```
import os

import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = os.environ.get("TOKEN")

from keep_alive import keep_alive

bot = commands. Bot(command_prefix="!", intents = discord. Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Up and Ready!")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print (f"Synced {len (synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)


@bot.tree.command (name="hello")
async def hello (interaction: discord. Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hey {interaction.user.mention}! This is a slash command!",
    ephemeral=True)

@bot.tree.command(name="say")
@app_commands.describe(thing_to_say="What should I say?")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f" {interaction.user.name} said: `{thing_to_say}`")


keep_alive()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

**The Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "/home/runner/IncredibleX/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/IncredibleX/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/IncredibleX/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/IncredibleX/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/runner/IncredibleX/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/IncredibleX/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 680, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 781d76eadf5df341 &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-12-30 20:18:25 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">781d76eadf5df341</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">34.138.198.247</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->
```

A working Bot with no Error that works 24/7

Comment: Replit's IP address(es) are being ratelimited by Discord

Comment: So what do i need to do ?

Comment: There is nothing that you can do about it other than switch away from Replit, or contact Replit's support team and see if they can put you on another ip address.

Comment: What could i use as an alternative ? VSCode ?

Comment: If you were to self-host it then yes, you could download Python and run it that way, however that will not be 24/7 unless you leave your device on.

Comment: Get an actual VPS and run your bot on that instead of abusing Replit's service for a discord bot. This is one of a couple dozen of issues that you'll encounter when using them.

Comment: See [more info about Replit being rate limited](https://ask.replit.com/t/discord-ratelimit/3522?u=not-ethan)

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue with discord bots in Replit caused by Discord's rate limiting. The easiest way to fix this is to type and enter `kill 1` in the shell to reset the connection. The bot will disconnect, so remember to press run to restart the bot.